# Jmeter assertion result listener as variable

Tags: jmeter, listener, assertion

My JMeter test plan looks like this:

```
HTTP Request
- Assertion
HTTP Request
- Assertion
HTTP Request
- Assertion
Assertion Result Listener
```

I'd like to define all assertion results from the listener as a variable and use that variable in a POST call to JIRA, so the description contains an overview of all assertions and failure and pass of each assertion.

[Assertion Result Listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPNes.png)

I know I can save the assertion results to a file and upload that, but I need the assertion results as text in the JIRA. Any ideas how I can do that?

edit: this is for a functional test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Thread Group
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def result = vars.get('result')
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
   if (result != null) {
       builder.append(result).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
   }


   prev.getAssertionResults().each { assertionResult ->
       builder.append(prev.getSampleLabel()).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
       if (assertionResult.isFailure()) {
           builder.append('\t').append(assertionResult.getFailureMessage()).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
       }
   }
   vars.put('result', builder.toString())
   props.put('result', builder.toString())
   ```
3. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
4. Refer the generated string holding the assertion results using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(result,)}`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Assertion Results into Variable]

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.